# Django: Abstract models cannot be instantiated for models for retrieving data

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

I am working on a project which has one abstract model and one main model for Djongo. When I try to insert a value, it is getting inserted without errors. But when I try to retrieve the data I get " Abstract models cannot be instantiated".

Here is my model:

```
class Exam_questions(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    options=ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50))
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    types=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract=True


    

class ExamDetails(models.Model):
    _id=ObjectIdField()
    exam_id=models.IntegerField(null=False,default=0)
    questions=models.EmbeddedField(model_container=Exam_questions)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

here is my code for querying:

```
def exams_questions(request,exam_id):
        get_exams=ExamDetails.objects.filter(exam_id=3)
        print(get_exams)
        return HttpResponse("hello") # have given this response only for testing
```

When I try to iterate or get values in the variable get_exams I am getting "Abstract models cannot be instantiated"  error. Please help!

Thanks

EDIT:
I fixed it . I did `pip install djongo` which downgraded the version of django from 3.2 to 3.0.5 which fixed the issue.

Comment: you have all your migrations applied?

Comment: Yes,all migrations have been applied . I have no issues inserting a record to the db. But retrieval is not working

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: This is models.py imports                                                                                         
 `from djongo import models
from djongo.models import ObjectIdField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField `

Comment: This is models.py imports                                                                                         
 `from djongo import models
from djongo.models import ObjectIdField  `This is my views.py import : `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .forms import UserForm
from .decorators import unauthenticated_student, allowed_users
from teacher.models import *
from exams.models import *
from exams.models import ExamDetails from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect,Http404`

Answer (score 7):

> it will be by Downgrading your django version to 3.1.12
> `pip install django==3.1.12`

Answer (score -2):

Remove the
Class Meta:
abstract=True
From Exam_questions class. And see

Comment: The Djongo documentation states "In case you don’t plan on using your embedded model as a standalone model (which means it will always be embedded inside a parent model) you should add the class Meta and abstract = True This way Djongo will never register this model as an actual model."

Therefore, some of us need this and removing it only leads to another error.